# count available agents in each timeslot sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with employee schedules:

```
create table dbo.schedules
(agentID int,
dayID int,
shiftStart time, 
break1Start time, 
break1stop time,
lunchStart time, 
lunchStop time, 
break2Start time,
break2Stop time,
shiftEnd time,
offindicator bit
)
```

I want to add up the number of available agents by 15 minute increments from 8:00 to 21:00.

How do I do this?

I so far have the following code to evaluate it:

```
select 
sum(case when offindicator = 1 or @timeslot < shiftStart or  (@timeslot >= 
break1Start and @timeslot <break1stop) OR (@timeslot >= break2Start and @timeslot <
break2stop) OR @timeslot >= shiftend then 0 else 1 end) [onoff]
from dbo.schedules
```

...but now I want a list of time slots and counts like:

```
DayID | Timeslot | Count

1 |   8:00  |  15

1 |  8:15   |  10

1 |  8:30   |  20

1 |  8:45   |  10
```

etc.

some sample data for the schedules table:

```
(   215,    1,  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   1   )
,(  215,    2,  '08:00',    '10:20',    '10:35',    '12:30',    '12:45',    '15:00',    '15:15',    '17:00',    0   )
,(  215,    3,  '08:00',    '10:20',    '10:35',    '12:30',    '12:45',    '15:00',    '15:15',    '17:00',    0   )
,(  215,    4,  '08:00',    '10:20',    '10:35',    '12:30',    '12:45',    '15:00',    '15:15',    '17:00',    0   )
,(  215,    5,  '08:00',    '10:20',    '10:35',    '12:30',    '12:45',    '15:00',    '15:15',    '17:00',    0   )
,(  215,    6,  '08:00',    '10:20',    '10:35',    '12:30',    '12:45',    '15:00',    '15:15',    '17:00',    0   )
,(  215,    7,  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   1   )
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: just added to the text of the question.

Comment: So your existing code counts up available agents for 1 timeslot at a time?

Comment: at the moment, yes.  but I want to be able to do it for all time slots, preferably without using a explicit loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by taking your `CASE` logic and using it in a `JOIN`, you'll need a driver table to get each timeslot for each agent/day, hence the `cte`:

By DayID/Timeslot:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT agentID,DayID, CAST('08:00' AS TIME) 'Timeslot'
             FROM #schedules
             UNION 
             SELECT agentID,DayID,DATEADD(MINUTE,15,Timeslot)
             FROM cte
             WHERE Timeslot < '21:00')                     
SELECT b.DayID,Timeslot,SUM(CASE WHEN a.agentID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM #schedules a
RIGHT JOIN cte b
 ON a.agentID = b.agentID
   AND a.dayID = b.DayID
   AND (offindicator = 1 
        OR b.Timeslot < shiftStart 
        OR (b.Timeslot >= break1Start AND b.Timeslot <break1stop) 
        OR (b.Timeslot >= break2Start AND b.Timeslot <break2stop) 
        OR b.Timeslot >= shiftend)
GROUP BY b.DayID,b.Timeslot
ORDER BY b.Timeslot,b.DayID
```

Or you can limit to a specific DayID:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT agentID,DayID, CAST('08:00' AS TIME) 'Timeslot'
             FROM #schedules
             UNION 
             SELECT agentID,DayID,DATEADD(MINUTE,15,Timeslot)
             FROM cte
             WHERE Timeslot < '21:00')                     
SELECT Timeslot,SUM(CASE WHEN a.agentID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM #schedules a
RIGHT JOIN cte b
 ON a.agentID = b.agentID
   AND a.dayID = b.DayID
   AND (offindicator = 1 
        OR b.Timeslot < shiftStart 
        OR (b.Timeslot >= break1Start AND b.Timeslot <break1stop) 
        OR (b.Timeslot >= break2Start AND b.Timeslot <break2stop) 
        OR b.Timeslot >= shiftend)
WHERE b.DayID = 1
GROUP BY b.Timeslot
```

Note:  Add `ALL` after the `UNION` in the `cte`, firewall prevents me from posting `UNION` and `ALL` next to each other.

Comment: this is close, but I need to split it out by dayID, so Monday has a different number of employees than Tuesday, and the way you set it up, it is summing across all days of the week.

Comment: Your example query doesn't specify dayID, so it wasn't apparent, updated answer, you can get a distribution by day/timeslot, or specify a day.