# Schedule Compliance Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know for every 15 minute interval from 8:00 to 21:00 of each of 7 dayID's and for each agentID how many minutes out of 15 the agent was in the "available" state i.e. that there is a record in the availability table.  For example, for agentID = 0107 below, between 8:00 and 8:15, he was available for 6.35 minutes.  note, in theory, there could be two records within that 15 minute range that must be added together.

Sample data from AVAILABILITY TABLE:

```
agentID |   DayID | statestart         |stateend

0107  |     2 | 08:00:57.7730000    |08:07:18.2000000

0107 |      2|  08:18:02.1370000|   09:07:39.5140000

0107 |      2|  09:18:46.9340000|   09:21:41.8520000
```

Some additional information/background on my question can be found at a previous (similar) question I asked: 
[count available agents in each timeslot sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361790/count-available-agents-in-each-timeslot-sql-server)

however, I believe this question should be standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a table with all 15 minute interval from 8:00 to 21:00 -> 52 rows and CROSS JOIN it.

This will return one row per overlapping interval:

```
SELECT agentid, dayid, t2.starttime,
   CASE WHEN t1.statestart > t2.starttime THEN t1.statestart ELSE t2.starttime END AS statestart,
   CASE WHEN t1.stateend < t2.endtime THEN t1.stateend ELSE t2.endtime END AS stateend
FROM tab AS t1 CROSS JOIN times AS t2
WHERE t1.statestart < t2.endtime
AND t1.stateend > t2.starttime
```

Based on that you can easily calculate the difference between statestart and stateend and sum it up GROUP BY agentid, dayid, t2.starttime